# frozen and busted water pipes?

Tags: water, repair, leak

Frozen and busted water pipe. That goes to my bathroom. The washer and bathroom sink and tub isn't working. But my kitchen sink is. My washer is also located in my bathroom. How far can it be frozen? We fixed the busted pipe and it still is acting like something from the drywall is clogged or frozen. What can I do? We own our home. And right now. We are in middle of a winter strong storm ice still is every were.

Comment: Please used mixed case for your post.  All capitals is not only hard to read, it is also considered as shouting.

Comment: You shut off water to the whole house and mop up the water you can find. Leave faucets open to drain lines. Wait for it to get warmer and start finding the busted pipes. Not fun…

Comment: Copper pipe, right?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. There's not enough information here for anyone to help with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

There are more frozen parts. Copper is an excellent conductor of heat, so if you can get a hair dryer or heat gun heating the pipe near the blockage, that'll melt it. All you need is a teeny tiny capillary passing the blockage. Flowing water will do the rest (if you have valves cracked while you heat the pipe). Alternatively, you can just turn off the home's water at night and when you're away to avoid flooding, but I would take a more proactive approach to avoid refreezing at the site of the breakage or additional locations.

The seals in the typical water lines from valves to sinks are heat sensitive, so if you heat one of the valves up, be sure to first disconnect the water line.

For avoiding blockages, a drip every 6 seconds will purge 5 ft of 1/2" water line every hour. A drip every 3 seconds will purge two 1/2" lines for 5 ft if you can balance the water from both lines.